# How to automatically hide wingpanel?

Tags: release-loki

How to automatically hide wingpanel in elementary OS 0.4 Loki?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

elementary has a full screen mode that might get close to what you're looking for. It's disabled by default, but you can enable it by going into the Settings app, editing keyboard shortcuts, and assigning a key to fullscreen mode.

[image]

In full screen mode, the top bar and plank aren't shown, and **each fullscreen app gets its own workspace** (<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle those).

Comment: Please See This  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y08u_bcJL-U . It has been implemented.

Comment: Refer to the below answer http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10226/4410

Comment: Try my fork: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/93

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with wingpanel.

Comment: Please See This youtube.com/watch?v=Y08u_bcJL-U . It has been implemented.

Comment: Refer to the below answer http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10226/4410

Comment: Yes it is: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/93

Comment: Not merged. So no it isn't.

Comment: Technically correct. Please help pressure upstream to adopt this feature (if not my specific pull request).

Answer (score 2):

What You want has been implemented by a person.

Here is its [LaunchPad Code](https://code.launchpad.net/~kbailey4444/wingpanel/dodge-maximize)

Follow This [Discussion](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/955498-add-optional-hide-mode) About its Development.
Refer [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y08u_bcJL-U) to see it in action.

Comment: Are you sure this works under 0.4 Loki?

Comment: I have just found it out , and video says it does , also see this discussion https://www.bountysource.com/issues/955498-add-optional-hide-mode . I have mailed the developer for further information.

Comment: I think it does but for 0.3 freya.

Comment: Maybe it does for loki too , have you tried it , i did not know how to update my wingpanel code to make it like launchpad version , you can test it .

Comment: The BountySource thread that you shared has a comment from Daniel Fore that explains why the team decided not to add this feature. The change was made against a pretty old version of Wingpanel, so even if the team wanted to make this change, it would take some work to merge that change into the latest version.

Comment: @RyanDeBeasi I know , but someone who wants it can himself install it through this launchpad code ,that is why i posted this answer and i don't know myself how do it so i have not added the steps , if you know how to reconfigure wingpanel through the launch pad code , feel free to edit the answer or you can also teach me.:)

Comment: That fork has not been updated for a long time, and is no longer compatible with elementary OS (Hera, etc.). I've reimplented its "dodge" mode as one of four autohide modes in my own fork: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/93

Answer (score 1):

After quite some searching I figured out there is no easy way to do this.. But what I do to kind of patch this problem is I use full screen mode (meta+f) which really fullscreens the current app. That together with the use of hot corners available in the behaviour settings of desktop, makes the problem less important, since i usually need fullscreen in the apps I'm working.

(Personally i have enabled a hot corner to show all windows)
The way FS mode works is by creating a separate workspace for the specific app, so meta+tab comes handy in stead of alt+tab quite often..

Comment: Try my fork: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/93

Answer (score 0):

I'm [working on this](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/93) for Juno+; unfortunately building [this fork](https://github.com/quequotion/wingpanel) requires a newer version of gtk3 (3.22 or higher) than the one shipped with Loki.

Answer (score 0):

A [blog post](https://entornosgnulinux.com/2018/01/01/autohide-en-wingpanel-para-elementary-os-loki/) gives perfect steps to do it in the current elementary OS 5.0 Juno. The post is in Spanish but it's easy to follow for a moderate linux user.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary
sudo apt update
sudo apt install elementary-wingautohide
```

Comment: This is NOT autohide, it's a script that kills and restarts wingpanel. This is autohide: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/93

Answer (score 0):

I have also written this program
https://github.com/mlibre/hide-wingpanel